# How do I only show certain items in a bootstrap navbar based on cookies in Python?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

My bootstrap navbar is in my base template and looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/post">New Post</a></li>   
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to make the navbar hide the New Post and Logout list items when the user is not signed in, and hide the Login and Register list items when he is. Any tips on how to make this possible?

If it helps, I'm using Python 2.7 with Jinja2 and I'm authenticating users with a cookie.

Comment: What framework do you use?

Comment: webapp2. I've learned mostly everything here from the CS253 course from Udacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
{% if user %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/post">New Post</a></li>  
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
{% elif not user %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Supposing you're passing to the template the variable `user` which depends on the presence or absence of the cookie. So you have to verify first in your view if the cookie is set and then pass the result to the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did exactly what I wanted it to do.